# Trigger Problems - opportunity-lineitem

Tags: trigger, opportunity-lineitem

i have a  trigger code thats updat a custom oppertunity fields with the details of a related product (we always have only one product each oppertunity).

```
trigger PrimaryProduct on Opportunity (before update) { 
    Map<Id,opportunitylineitem> oppMap=new Map<Id,opportunitylineitem>(); 
    for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT id,(SELECT id ,product2.name, opportunityId,UnitPrice,Quantity 
  from opportunitylineitems)FROM Opportunity WHERE id IN:Trigger.new ]){ 
        if(opp.opportunitylineitems.size() > 0) oppMap.put(opp.Id,opp.opportunitylineitems[0]); } 

    for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){ 
        opp.Opportunity_Prim_Product_Name__c = oppMap.get(opp.Id).product2.name; 
        opp.product_qunt__c=oppMap.get(opp.Id).Quantity; 
        opp.product_salesprice__c=oppMap.get(opp.Id).UnitPrice; } }
```

when trying to update an oppertunity with no related product , im getting the next error :

> Error:Apex trigger PrimaryProduct caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: PrimaryProduct: execution of BeforeUpdate
>   caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object: Trigger.PrimaryProduct: line 8, column 1.

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Well, apparently there are no OLI and you are not checking if the map contains the key before you try to grab a value `product2.name` for a map value that does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are checking `opp.opportunitylineitems.size() > 0` before putting the Order Line Item in the map, you should do the same check before you take values off from that map.

```
for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){ 
    if(oppMap.containsKey(opp.Id)) {
        opp.Opportunity_Prim_Product_Name__c = oppMap.get(opp.Id).product2.name; 
        opp.product_qunt__c=oppMap.get(opp.Id).Quantity; 
        opp.product_salesprice__c=oppMap.get(opp.Id).UnitPrice; }}
```

Comment: well, you are most defiantly right.     thanks man!

Answer (score -1):

You need to have that for loop skip in cases where there are no OLIs. a simple addition should fix it

```
for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){ 
    if(!oppMap.containsKey(opp.id))
        continue;
    ...
```